# PHP search string on multi files on subfolders

Tags: php

Hello i'm trying to make box search by tipping something found already on a file

here my code sounds dosent working

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$dir = '/lol/';
$files = scandir($dir,1);
foreach ($files as $lines){
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
    if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
    echo $line;
    }
}
?>
</center>
  </div>
</div>
        <h3>Search by full email address or username. Example: user@test.com, usertest</h3>
<form action="a.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>        <p>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `/lol/` means "search from root of your disk". Set absolute path to your `lol` folder.

Comment: If your `lol` dir is in the same location as your script, you can get that full path via `$dir = __DIR__.'/lol/';`